# Accessing Page Method Request Headers

Tags: asp.net

Inside a page method, how can I get access to the current request object so that I can read the headers?

The method looks like

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string MyMethod(string name)
 {
 }
```

And lives in an aspx.cs file that inherits from Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Request.Headers` property in your code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string MyMethod(string name)
 {
   var headers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers;   
   foreach(var item in header)
   {

   }
 }
```

Comment: can you post your code Jarrod, because i think property of page you can get

Comment: Try: HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.  But @Candie made a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
[WebMethod]        
public static string MyMethod(string name)
{
      var headers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers;         
}
```

`HttpContext.Current` returns the [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) associated with the current request. You can use it to process any data associated with the request.